# What can cause Spring IoC instantiate more than one instance of a singleton bean per WebApp?

Tags: spring, dependency-injection

I have a Spring based WebApp. In my application context, I have this bean defined:

```
<bean id="someSingleton" class="com.fake.SomeSingleton" scope="singleton"/>
```

I have the one Spring dispatch servlet definition and one class that has the `@Controller` annotation to which I auto-wired this bean, expecting Spring to only ever instantiating this class once. However, according to the following debug code, Spring is instantiating this class more than once:

```
private static final Semaphore SANITY_CHECK = new Semaphore(1);

public FakeSingleton(){
    if(!SANITY_CHECK.tryAcquire()){
      log.error("why?");
      System.exit(-1);
    else{
      log.error("OK");
    }
}
```

What can be the cause?

Note: I use spring 3.1.2.RELEASE

**EDIT:**
Thanks to the hints I was given, I found the culprit.
Apart from the DispatcherServlet, I also had a ContextLoaderListener in my web.xml. After removing it, SomeSingleton only got instantiated once.

```
<!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>FakeService</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few possible reasons:

- Your class is wrapped by some CGLIB proxy which causes the constructor to run twice (as opposed to `@PostConstruct` callback which always runs once per bean) - once for your class and once for inheriting proxy
- more likely, your bean is being picked up by two contexts: main one and Spring MVC one. This is a poor practice and you should avoid it. Check out if your `SomeSingleton` class is not picked up by MVC dispatcher servlet context via some CLASSPATH scanning.

BTW in such a code it's safe to use simple `AtomicInteger` instead of `Semaphore`.

Comment: Could you please explain your first point some more? Why would the proxy not work just like any other inheriting class and invoke super() (the constructor of the bean being proxied) just once?

Answer (score 1):

A singleton is once per context, not once-per-heat-death-of-the-universe.

Turn on logging and see why/if the entire app context is being created more than once.